# Manual copying from WebBrowser is not working

Tags: c#, browser

Manual copying from `WebBrowser` is not working: when I right-click on the image inside my `Form->WebBrowser` and then `Copy`, when I paste it in Microsoft Paint nothing is being copied.

Here is the properties of the `WebBrowser`:

[image]

Comment: Would you provide more context please? Which WebBrowser? Are you talking about a Web browser control on a XAML or WinForms form?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst WinForms

Comment: To make sure I understand your goal: you're you expecting the Copy command to copy an image from an HTML document being viewed in the WebBrowser, yes?

Comment: @adv12 by hovering over it and copying it yeh

Comment: I *think*, but don't *know*, that the Copy command in this situation will just copy whatever text is selected, rather than the image you're hovering.  Probably not what you want.  I've heard the HTML Agility Pack can be useful for parsing the HTML for, e.g., finding the URL of the image so you can download it and do what you want with it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null)
```